# Different exchange rates in TaxTrans and LedgerTrans [AX 2009]

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, axapta

Hello I have a problem with Exchange rates in Dynamics AX 2009.
In TaxTrans table is different exchange rate than in LedgerTrans table.
In PurchParameters table Exchange Date Rate is set to DocumentDate but in TaxTrans is get exchange rate from TransDate.

Comment: In all lines of TaxTrans? You have a customization for that part?

Comment: In MarkupTrans - Freight, I changed also in TaxParameters value to "DocumentDate" in field TaxCalculationDateType, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with that? Sounds like normal accounting behavior. You have provided an incomplete question with little to go on, so this answer could be wrong if you add more info.

Let's say your company operates in `USD` and today is June 10.

If you receive an invoice dated June 1 in `CAD`, your `document date` would be June 1, and your exchange rate would be the rate as of June 1. This depends on your accounting, but normally you want to know your cost on the date you accrued it...not the date you happened to transact it. This can give you more accurate costing.

Then when you pay a bill or whatever, the tax will be on the date of the transaction, so you will want the exchange rate on that transaction date.